# Elasticsearch Error ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [] uncaught exception in thread [main]

Tags: java, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

Elasticsearch version: v5.4.1

OS version: windows 10

Steps to reproduce:
Ran elasticsearch from the command prompt

```
LOGS(if needed):
[2017-06-21T11:50:11,185][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: plugins directory [C:\elasticsearch\plugins] not found
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:127) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:114) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:67) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:122) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:88) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:91) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:84) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: plugins directory [C:\elasticsearch\plugins] not found
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Spawner.spawnNativePluginControllers(Spawner.java:72) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:167) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:350) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:123) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
        ... 6 more
```

I installed elasticsearch from zip and started with `.\bin\elasticsearch.bat` from cmd

Comment: Did you happen to figure this out? I'm experiencing the same thing.

Comment: Yeah the new version of elasticsearch 6.2 fixed the issue.